# C# How to group different Form Controls together?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am using Windows Forms.

I do only have one Frame. In this Frame I organized some Controls together. Where the Controls in one Row belong together (they form an Object). And overall I have five of those Rows, with the same Controls.

Eg.: Name , Surname, Age, Income, etc (in one Row)
There are Dropdownlists, Checkboxes, NumicUpDown, etc

I would now need to know an way to "bind" them together. The same counts for the Events. Because at the moment I would make for every different Control an Event and then distuingish them by an Number at the end of the Controls Name, which would be rather annoying. And then generate from that the Object.

What way do I have to not make dozens of Events and indicate that everything in one Row belongs together?

Comment: Don't invent your own grid control.  If you don't like DataGridView then go shopping.

Answer (score 0):

For grouping them together on the Form (not Frame) - put them all on one Panel.

To use the same even handler for all of them - simply subscribe to the same one. (Using the designer - select the events, and choose from the drop down. For doing this from code - just do `YourControl2.EventName += YourControl1.EventName`.) Note that this is not possible for every type of Control and every event. It's only possible if the events have the same signature.

Comment: Sorry if I was too unspecific, but that´s exactly what I didn´t wanted to do. With that I would have to differ between the "Rows" and also between the different Controls in one Row. Or am I somewhere wrong?...

Comment: @EsoMoa I don't understand what you're saying exactly. Let's take this one by one - what do you mean by `I would have to differ between the "Rows"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a UserControl. Right-click the project or a folder in the project and select UserControl. You can then add controls to it, in the designer, just as for Forms.

Once you have compiled the project, your UserControl will appear at the top of the toolbox and you can drag and drop it onto a form.

Like this would would create a user control representing one row, and add one of them for each row to your form. You can also add additional properties, methods and events to your user control class. They will automatically appear in the properties window.

---

But in your case, a [DataRepeater Control for Windows Forms](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms/) would be appropriate. It is part of the [Visual Basic Power Packs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169), but just works as well in C# projects.

Comment: Thanks, for the idea of the own UserControl, didn´t thought about it. But wouldn´t be there the same Problem as I described above? I would add one single Event per UserControl and then inside this Event I would have to distuingish between the different Control´s.  Isn´t it the same thing just that it´s "cleaner"?

Comment: It is cleaner to use some grid control that uses some data binding mechanism. Create a class containing properties that will make up the columns of the grid. Bind a list of objects of this class to the grid and in the events get the current item with `grid.SelectedItem`, `grid.FocusedItem` or whatever the grid is providing. Good grid controls allow you to use dropdowns, check boxes etc.

Comment: The data repeater has a `CurrentItem` property for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

take all your controlls in one Panel. So You can with group more RadioButtons and they can know one for anderer. Then you can between them scwiching so you becomming what you whant.